# Pandas - Create new column with value based on the name of the other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as below

```
Col 1   Col 2       Col 3   Col 4
 ID01 1010000000    469    -469
 ID01 1010000001    349    -349
 ID01 1010000002    936    -4936
 ID01 1010000003    733    -38733
```

and i want to add 2 new columns, column 5 and 6
where the column 5 will have values based on the name of the column 3 and 4, and column 6 will have values from column 3 and 4.

so the final df will be like this

```
Col 1   Col 2       Col 3   Col 4  Col 5   Col 6
 ID01 1010000000    469    -469    Col 3   469
 ID01 1010000001    349    -349    Col 3   349
 ID01 1010000002    936    -4936   Col 3   936
 ID01 1010000003    733    -38733  Col 3   733
 NaN  NaN           NaN     NaN    col 4   -469
 NaN  NaN           NaN     NaN    col 4   -349
 NaN  NaN           NaN     NaN    col 4   -4936
 NaN  NaN           NaN     NaN    col 4   -38733
```

any ideas on how can i achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.join(
    df[['Col3','Col4']].stack()
    .droplevel(0)
    .rename_axis('Col5')
    .rename('Col6')
    .sort_index()
    .reset_index(),how='right'))
```